# how can read value from firebase to Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how can read value from firebase to Android?

I had write value to firebase, but how can read value to android?

my code

```
private String userid;
private TextView username;
username = findViewById(R.id.username);


 firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserModel userModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                username.setText(userModel.getUsername());
                //publisher.setText(userModel.getUsername());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

But I got the error code

> Process: com.luvtas.campingau, PID: 23997
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.luvtas.campingau/com.luvtas.campingau.Ui.PostActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

where has problem?

and because I want to get current userid from firebase to get user name and profile image.

Comment: `userid` is null, from the code you've posted, i can't see where you've assigned it a value, so it makes sense that your app would crash

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813053/cant-pass-null-for-argument-pathstring-in-child-in-firebase-database/45813675
you can go through this link.It was posted by someone 3 years back but error is quite similar.And I was somehow able to solve using this.

Comment: As a_local_nobody mentioned in his comment, the `userid` is null. Are you sure the user is authenticated?

Comment: @a_local_nobody because I want to get current userid from firebase to get user name and profile image

Comment: @AlexMamo because I want to get current userid from firebase to get user name and profile image

Answer (score 1):

It seems your String "userid" is null that is why you are getting an error so you need to pass the actual userid in the string userid to do this you can run the following code:

```
private String userid;
private TextView username;
username = findViewById(R.id.username);

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserModel userModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
            username.setText(userModel.getUsername());
            //publisher.setText(userModel.getUsername());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: thx bro, I have other question, if I want to get image url. how can modity this ?
use private Context context? 

Glide.with(context).load(userModel.getUserimage());

Comment: just say 

In Activity:



Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(userModel.getUserimage()).into("whatever view you want to load image").

In Fragment:


Glide.with(getContext()).load(userModel.getUserimage()).into("whatever view you want to load image").